# C++ - writing to static variables from different objects require a mutex?

Tags: mutex, crud, static-variables

I have a base class with a static std::map variable, something like below :

```
  class base
  {
     public : static std::map <int, int> my_statistics;
  }
```

I have a derived class which reads, updates, writes to this static variable. Since this derived class is instantiated by different processes at run time, and I'm not sure whether they will be sequential or not. I wanted to know whether I would be requiring a mutex_lock over the static variable every time I read (reader lock) or write to it (writer Lock).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : It is not the processes which are instantiating this class, but different objects which shall instantiate this class. So, I wanted to know whether different objects writing (or reading) to a static variable is safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Different processes cannot share same object instance, so that your question is not meaningful. "static" is only meaningful in process. If you want different processes to access same memory, you should use shared memory.

New answer to your EDIT:

If your process is not multi-threaded, then you don't need to protect. If there are several threads that read/write the static var, then you need to protect it.

Comment: If your process is not multi-threaded, then you don't need to protect. If there are several threads that read/write the static var, then you need to protect it.